# How to load all information Currency properties by currency code?

Tags: 8

I used module Currency version 8.x-3.1 . I had currency Code so I looking up function to load all properties currency by currency code , What API or function do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it would be more helpful for you to ask in the module's issue forum?

Answer (score 0):

As a currency is just an entity you can do the following:

```
$currency_code = 'AUD';
$entity_type_manager = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');
$currency = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('currency')->load($currency_code);
ksm($currency); //check out what's available

//eg get sign
$sign = $currency->get('sign');
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the commerce_currency entity with entity manager

```
    $entity_manager = \Drupal::entityManager();
    $currency_code = 'USD';
    $currency = $entity_manager->getStorage('commerce_currency')->load($currency_code);
    kint($currency);
```